# Power integrity design review of LED driver and audio amplifier PCB

Tags: circuit-design, power-integrity

I am seeking advice on improving the power integrity of a PCB featuring a [HT16K33](https://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/HT16K33v120.pdf) driving 6 segment LEDs and a YX8002 (equivalent to [LM4871](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4871.pdf?ts=1705253581176&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FLM4871)) audio amplifier. Decoupling capacitors C7 and C16 are placed physically as close as possible to the respective power pins and are connected to the ground plane (IC pin – cap pin – via pin). The circuit is currently powered by a linear bench power supply and draws around 150 mA at 5 V in idle, i.e. with the segment LEDs turned on and the speaker muted.

[image: Display schematic]

[image: Audio schematic]

The 5 V power rail drops by up to 500 mV while the LED driver is multiplexing through the LEDs; in worst case, when all LEDs are driven in 1 Hz blink mode, the power supply is emitting a noticeable hissing sound:

[image: Display distortion]

When the amplifier is turned on as well, the power rail is distorted even further and the LEDs become visibly dimmer during the loudest parts of the audio sample:

[image: Audio distortion]

What I have tried so far to improve the situation:

- Increased the decoupling capacitor C16 of the LED driver U5 from 100 nF (as suggested by the datasheet, but as I have learned, this is largely a [myth](https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/articles/1589-the-myth-of-three-capacitor-values) these days) to 10 uF (the largest MLCC cap I had at hand). This seems to have no effect at all.
- Tried to add several different electrolytic capacitors in the range of 10s and 100s of uF in parallel to C16 (admittedly in a crude way, by pressing the capacitor leads against the power and ground pins of U5, as I had not planned for an additional decoupling capacitor footprint). This smooths down the distortion somewhat (in the sense that it always looks more like the second scope screenshot with the audio amplifier being turned on), but the same distortion pattern is still visible and the user-facing issues (dimmed LEDs and PSU hissing) do not go away.
- Tried different power supplies – one fares better than the others in absolute voltage drop, but the distortion pattern is always the same.

**How can I improve the power integrity of my design? Is this even a decoupling issue or something else?**

To put the question in a broader context: This PCB is part of a larger project where up to a dozen of similar modules (in terms of power consumption) can be plugged into a common power rail. **What should I keep in mind from a per-module and power supply (to be supplied by a battery) perspective to achieve a sound power integrity?**

Comment: Where are you measuring the 5 V ? Are the wires thick enough and the traces wide enough?

Comment: I have both measured at the power supply connector as well as at the IC pins, but the difference is not large, a few 10s of mV. I am using 0,25 mm traces and 0,8 / 0,4 mm vias for everything.

Comment: Is the PSU in current-limiting mode?

Comment: You're using a switching power converter module? Layout is everything, and the module you're using may be crap if it's one of those "Amazon" or Aliexpress finds. What you're seeing is not something that we can solve by looking at the schematic. Show the layout, better yet upload the whole KiCad project to github so we can actually take a good look at it and suggest changes electronically in the same medium.

Comment: *the power supply is emitting a noticeable hissing sound* The bench power supply??? It's not supposed to do that. Do a dynamic load test on the supply itself. If it's an "Amazon" find, it may be total crap. That's the thing with those no-name products: it's entirely on the end user to qualify them for any sort of an application. Just because there's a "lab supply" label slapped on it doesn't mean it sometimes won't be a piece of junk that's a lesson in how not to cut engineering corners.

Comment: I've put several such circuits together, using even more power-hungry drive circuitry - just plain old TTLs, and many more segments. The 5V supply is rock solid. Such circuits, without ground/power planes, just judiciously laid out traces, were commonplace in bench instruments. E.g. I have a Valhalla Scientific 2701C programmable DC source with 7 8-segment displays that run fairly inefficient LEDs, so they consume more power than your display. The 5V line on the plug-in display board moves maybe 50mV worst case.

Comment: 0.25mm=10 mil. That's *thin* traces. The common cathodes should use thicker traces - say 20 or 30 mil. And the supply lines to the driver IC should be much thicker - 50 mil, or ideally use partial power planes. Again, without a layout to look at, we can't help you any further. With layout I can just go ahead and redo it in a couple minutes to make it clear what's wrong. I can also try and extract the finite-element spice model out of the copper, so that you'll see what those copper traces actually look like in terms of resistive elements.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for taking a look, I have uploaded the KiCad project here: https://gitlab.com/sephalon/ktane4realz-countdown_timer-eda

Comment: If the power supply itself is dropping out of regulation it's probably overloaded or faulty. I would try a different (higher capacity) one first to rule that out. Probably also a good idea to measure your actual current draw too in case it's larger than you expect.

Comment: Unrelated but it looks to me like your +3.3V rail is not powered by anything.

Comment: So to rule out any supply-side limitations, I hooked the circuit up to the 5 V rail of an ATX power supply (via AWG 26 wires), but even with that I only see marginal improvements - so looks like this is really a PCB issue.

Comment: With the HT16K33 sinking around 30 mA per row and a maximum of 10 segments connected per column, the display would draw around 300 mA worst-case. The audio amplifier draws up to 600 mA (but of course I do not drive it to the maximum at all). With my power supply net having a total length of 30 cm alone, a trace resistance calculator tells me that I would have a voltage drop of several hundred mV – so in my current understanding this indeed seems to be the main issue here.

Comment: I would still appreciate @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica having a look at the PCB layout (https://gitlab.com/sephalon/ktane4realz-countdown_timer-eda) to rule out any other issues.